# PHP decrypt with Rijndael-128

Tags: php, aes, encryption, rijndael

I have a function in php which decrypt as the title.
This function decode from base64 and decrypt correctly:

```
function decrypt($base64encoded_ciphertext) {

    $key = 'a16byteslongkey!a16byteslongkey!';

    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $plaintext = trim($plaintext);

    //Sostituisco tutti i caratteri fasulli
    for($i=0; $i<32; $i++) $plaintext = str_replace(chr($i), "", $plaintext);

    return $plaintext;
}
```

But..if i send in input this string: **Da/itClhHEVQH9BfL/gIug==**

it return this: **100000065912248XNš!†Özé‰ÎªãaóÒ]`-ÐüõÁÔ…ayã›[¿gp—›s.ýý 3á«uÛ§hZ¼ú™R2.**

instead of only **100000065912248**

I have tried with a tool online and a encrypted string is correctly..

[image: the online tool]

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` if you're not using an IV? And why is there a `for` loop that blindly strips a whole bunch of characters?

Comment: only CBC decrypt correctly..the others not work..i have a for because at the end of a correctly string, there are cur(3) or chr(4)...

Comment: That's not the point. The point is you're using cryptography incorrectly. Don't just try to randomly modify settings and strip characters until it works. That's a dangerous thing to do. If there are chr(3) and chr(4) at the end of the string, that's because you've made a mistake when encrypting, decrypting, or both. This should **not** be needed. And if you're going to use CBC, use an IV.

Comment: And whoever wrote that tool is a noob himself. They don't seem to have a clue of what they're doing.

Comment: why online tool work? and why with other string my function work?

Comment: Like I told you, the online tool is wrong. It's possible they've made the same mistake you did. The fact that you have to strip characters means that it **doesn't** work correctly. Encryption and decryption should be totally transparent. Where's the code you used to encrypt this?

Comment: Sorry..i have found a problem...a stupid error in GET params..
I encrypt string without IV..and decrypt without IV..Thanks

Comment: @NullUserException Well at least he's not using the official example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php